# Microphone audio capture in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, microphone, audiocontext

I'm trying to get audio stream using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.
This works fine in Firefox, unfortunatly not in Chrome.
have done al this with a secure page (thus https) but Chome does not react on "onAudioProcess" function.

in console, Firefox shows the audio chunks captured by microphone. But Chrome does not show anythink.

Does anybody have an idea?
that would be great.

a working jsfiddle example can be shown here:
https://jsfiddle.net/aminekassir/3fjxq7wr/2/

````html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn_001" value="Click" />
```html

```javascript
console.log(adapter.browserDetails.browser);

$(function () {
  $('#btn_001').click(function () {
    console.log('start recording');
    startRecording();
  });
});

const mediaConstraints = window.constraints = { audio: true, video: false };
const micBufferSize = 512;
var audioCtx; 

function startRecording() {

  if (typeof AudioContext === 'function') {
    console.log('AudioContext defined');
    audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  } else if (typeof webkitAudioContext === 'function') {
    console.log('webkitAudioContext defined');
    audioCtx = new webkitAudioContext();
  } else if (typeof mozAudioContext === 'function') {
    console.log('mozAudioContext defined');
    audioCtx = new mozAudioContext();
  } else {
    console.error('Web Audio not supported!');
  }

  console.log('audioCtx', audioCtx);
  audioCtx.resume();

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(onMicrophoneStream).catch(onMicrophoneStreamError);

  console.log('hasOwnProperty("createScriptProcessor")', window.AudioContext.prototype.hasOwnProperty('createScriptProcessor'));

  function onMicrophoneStream(stream) {
    console.log('onMicrophoneStream', stream);
    let micStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var scriptProcessorNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(micBufferSize, 1, 1);
    scriptProcessorNode.onaudioprocess = onAudioProcess;
    micStream.connect(scriptProcessorNode);
  }
  function onMicrophoneStreamError(e) {
    console.log('onMicrophoneStreamError', e);
  }

  function onAudioProcess(e) {
    //console.log('onAudioProcess');
    if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
      audioCtx.resume();
    }
    var micOutBuff = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // incoming microphone stream is Float32
    console.log(micOutBuff);
  }
}
```javascript
````